# VirusTotal desktop file uploader seems infected

Tags: virus, antivirus, virus-removal

I wanted to scan my process with VirusTotal.com and for this I downloaded `vtuploader2.2.exe` from their [website](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/desktop-applications/#sending-files).

Before executing, I uploaded it to VirusTotal.com and scanned it for viruses to make sure this file was clean.

To my surprise it showed it was infected with a virus `Trojan.Nsis.Agent.eaudhx`. Detailed analysis report is on this [page](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/0918fa4b22d3e212a13fa449a5a7b5c3ec97759dd87db6d281f387b1570e13c9/analysis/1460260188/).

Can anyone tell me if this is a false alarm or is it actually a virus? I had never heard of Antivirus `NANO-Antivirus`.

How can I upload all of the active processes for scanning?

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that's a virus? Ok, according to VT there is only one detection by `NANO-Antivirus`. In cases like this one, I like to check file in sandbox to see what's happening.

So based on static and dynamic analyze with cuckoo sandbox, I don't see nothing which indicate to be a malicouse file.

```
File Name   vtuploader2.2.exe
File Size   142744 bytes
File Type   PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive

MD5     43cd42fe47af2256e4414264f49af1a8
SHA1    3ccbbfffd0da76f72dd99ac39afcfdfacd5f16e2
SHA256  0918fa4b22d3e212a13fa449a5a7b5c3ec97759dd87db6d281f387b1570e13c9
```

Here is fresh report:

https://malwr.com/analysis/NmIyYWM4NDI1YThmNDc3ZWEzODQ3ZjIzNWRiNDJmN2E/#

> Probably harmless! There are strong indicators suggesting that this file is safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Only 1 of 55 scanners detected anything and the report says

> Probably harmless! There are strong indicators suggesting that this file is safe to use

I'd go with trusting the file.

Comment: Wanted to be on a safer side